# How do you do a search and replace inside a vim function?

Tags: function, vim

I'm trying to a write a function that runs search and replace on a range.

I know that one can do `:2,5 s/some pattern/something else/` to do this as a vim command, but I can't figure out how this would work inside a function definition. Initially, I tried

```
function! MyFunc() range
  a:firstline,a:lastline s/some pattern/something else/
endfunction
```

but when I try to load that function in, I get the error `Missing :endfunction`. I also tried with call, as I've noticed in other tutorials and examples that sometimes call is used in situations like this. I tried both `call a:firstline,a:lastline s/some pattern/something else/` and `a:firstline,a:lastline call s/some pattern/something else/`. With this, the function loaded. But when I tried calling the function with doing `:2,4 call MyFunc()`, I get a `Missing parenthesis` error pointing at the search/replace line.

Can anyone help me with this? I have yet to find any examples of how to do search and replace in a function call.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting the error `Missing :endfunction`  because function definition is incomplete. Try the one given below, should work

```
function! MyFunc() range
  execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/some pattern/something else/'
endfunction
```

Comment: Missing `:endfunction` is because dummy parser that records function body thinks `a:firstline` starts `:append` command which eats everything till the line with a single dot. If you add such line and another `endfunction` after it you will though get an expected error as `:append` command cannot be followed by `:firstline`.

Comment: Ahh... execute... nice. For what it's worth, I finally found a nice tutorial that covers this - http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html. Thanks for breaking me through that one!

Comment: Also worth noting that the use of single quotes is best...although...I'm not entirely sure why that is. When I used double quotes, `\n` was interpreted as a null, which is the documented vim behavior, yet when single quoted, was interpreted as a newline.